# Receive notification when the number of records in the table reaches a certain number

Tags: python, mysql

I want to reach lucky customers. For this, I want to receive notification when the number of orders reaches 10,000 and its multiples. (Like the lucky customer who placed the 100,000th order) Order information is in a mysql database. The table like this:

```
id  order_id  customer_name   .....
1   1         alex 
2   2         david
3   3         julia
4   4         nicole
....
```

I tried this:

1. Connect to mysql database with python
2. Pull Order Number
3. Calculate **order count** mod **10.000**
4. With the if-else structure, if the result is equal to 10,000, send an e-mail to the e-mail address I defined.
5. Schedule this python script (every hour ? every minute ? is it right to run it so often  ?

But catching the number 10,000 in a constantly updated database will be difficult. How can I do that ? can i do this with trigger function ?

Comment: You have many questions in one, some of which are opinion based (for instance the frequency is arbitrary, you can do what you want)

Comment: You can use trigger, but in my case I dont suggest it, it is better to make it on the code you are running, inorder to make changes and you can always see the code logic and the error will stay there. Making changes to the database might be tricky and can damage.

Comment: This is a prime use case for a database trigger.